# __scanCodes is not defined vision-camera-code-scanner [React Native]

Tags: react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I'm getting the following error, as a lot of other people report on issues.

```
__scanCodes is not defined
```

It occurs both on iOS and Android.

Here's my libraries version:

```
"react-native": "^0.70.6",
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.2",
"vision-camera-code-scanner": "^0.2.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0",
```

And finally the babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  plugins: [
    ["react-native-reanimated/plugin", { globals: ["__scanCodes"] }],
    "module:react-native-dotenv",
  ],
};
```

I have also tried to patch react-native-vision-camera, following this instructions:
https://github.com/rodgomesc/vision-camera-code-scanner/issues/79#issuecomment-1278937809

Here's the code I'm using:

```
const [frameProcessor, barcodes] = useScanBarcodes([BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE], { checkInverted: true });
```

And here's the Xcode error:

```
Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Real-cktefjzimocjmeeqhtpyfxgfpixu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/vision-camera-code-scanner/vision_camera_code_scanner.modulemap' not found
```

Does someone have a solution for this issue? Or does a patch exist to solve the problem?
Thank you

Comment: how do you use it with hook `useScanBarcodes` or with `useFrameProcessor` and `scanBarcodes` function?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I don't know why `useScanBarcodes` hook is not working. Working solution is like:

```js
import {
  Camera,
  useCameraDevices,
  useFrameProcessor,
} from 'react-native-vision-camera';
import { scanBarcodes, BarcodeFormat } from 'vision-camera-code-scanner';

const CameraView = () => {
  const devices = useCameraDevices();
  const device = devices.back;
  const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor(
    frame => {
      'worklet';
      const detectedBarcodes = scanBarcodes(frame, [BarcodeFormat. QR_CODE], {checkInverted: true });
      const barcode = detectedBarcodes[0];
      if (barcode) { {
        runOnJS(setBarcodes)(barcode);
      }
    },
    [],
  );

  return (
        <CameraView
          device={device}
          isActive={true}
          frameProcessor={frameProcessor}
          frameProcessorFps={5}
          orientation="portrait"
        />
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok Thank you very much, but now the pod installation fails wit this error:  changed the constraints of dependency `GTMSessionFetcher/Core` inside your development pod `vision-camera-code-scanner`.

Comment: @PaulRock try to use this versions `"react-native-vision-camera": "2.15.2",` and `"vision-camera-code-scanner": "0.2.0",` and `"react-native-reanimated": "2.13.0",` also don't forget to run `yarn` and `pod install --project-directory=ios --repo-update`

Comment: Ok I remove and reinstall node_modules (includes yarn.lock) and the deintegrate and reinstall pods, but the error still persist on Xcode

Comment: what is your versions of `GTMSessionFetcher/Core` in `Podfile.lock`?

Comment: GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.7.2)

Comment: maybe you have another packages which has the same pod but with another version

Comment: another thing, I'm using the login with google library too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250849/discussion-between-kirill-novikov-and-paul-rock).

Comment: exaclty, I think google sign-in is using 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `globals: ['__scanCodes']` to your `babel.config.js` file as following:

```js
...
],
[
  'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  {
    globals: ['__scanCodes'],
  },
],
...
```

Then `yarn start --reset-cache` and rebuild the application.

Answer (score 0):

your missing an extra array literal []

...
plugins: [
[
"react-native-reanimated/plugin",
{
globals: ['__scanCodes'],
}
]
]
...

Answer (score 0):

***step  1 : add these lines in babel.config.js***

```js
plugins: [
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      {
        globals: ['__scanCodes'],
      },
    ],
  ],
```

***than must run this :***

1. npx react-native clean
2. rm -rf node_modules
3. rm -rf ios/build android/build
4. npm install
5. npx react-native run-android